# Operations on Sequences - Codewars Kata - Best Performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

This is a [codewars problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5e4bb05b698ef0001e3344bc). The idea is given that `arr = [x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), ..., x(i), x(i+1), ..., x(m), x(m+1)]` where all `x(i)` are positive integers. (the length (`len(arr)`) of this array will be a positive multiple of 4)

And let `P = (x(1) ** 2 + x(2) ** 2) * (x(3) ** 2 + x(4) ** 2) * ... * (x(m) ** 2 + x(m+1) ** 2)`

Find `A` and `B` such that `A**2 + B**2 == P`

If only one solution is found, it is already valid.

I solved, but the efficiency is low. Initially I wrote this:

**[Original Method]**

```py
from math import sqrt, ceil

def solve(arr):
    if len(arr) % 2 != 0: return []
    n = len(arr)
    P = 1
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        P *= (arr[i]**2 + arr[i + 1]**2)
        i += 2
    m = ceil(sqrt(P))
    for A in range(1, m):
        B = sqrt(P - A**2)
        if B == int(B):
            return [A, int(B)]
    return []
```

To improve the performance I tried to use the [Cauchy inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

**[Improvement but Failing]**

```py
from math import sqrt, ceil

def solve(arr):
    if len(arr) % 4 != 0: return []
    n = len(arr)
    P = 1
    for i in range(0, n, 2):
        P *= (arr[i]**2 + arr[i + 1]**2)
    C = 1
    D = 1
    for i in range(0, n, 4):
        C *= (arr[i]**2 + arr[i + 1]**2) * (arr[i + 2]**2 + arr[i + 3]**2)
        D *= (arr[i] * arr[i + 2] + arr[i + 1] * arr[i + 3])**2
        A = int(sqrt(D))
        B = int(sqrt(P - A**2))
        if A ** 2 + B ** 2 == P:
            return [A, B]
    return []
```

But the code above starts having problems for high numbers. For example: `arr = [3, 9, 8, 4, 6, 8, 7, 8, 4, 8, 5, 6, 6, 4, 4, 5]` should result in `A = 13243200` and `B = 25905600`, but my result is that not has A and B for this case.

**I need help to improve my performance. I don't know if using the Cauchy inequality solves it, but if you have another idea it's already valid.**

Comment: What happened when you used `isqrt` instead of `sqrt`?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, but it didn't make a difference in performance. Since I use `ceil(sqrt(value))` it does the same as `isqrt`. But it helps to make it a little cleaner.

Comment: I think the big problem is this `for`: `for A in range(1, m):`. Why `P` is a high value. And even if I use `m = ceil(sqrt(P))`, it's still a costly cycle.

Comment: I didn't mean it for performance but for accuracy. If you go through floats, you'll lose accuracy with big numbers. That said, I now solved it with a completely different approach, and apparently everybody else used the same. It's funny, this was a small part in a talk I once gave in a number theory seminar.